# Where should ruby option parsing be?

Tags: ruby, command, command-line-arguments

I'm wondering where would be the best place to do option parsing in ruby, when creating a gem, with the traditional (bin/, lib/, test/) folder hierarchy.

Specifically, should options be parsed in the executable file in (bin/) or in a runner class in lib/? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen it done both ways. Personally, I think much of it depends on your gem; if the option parsing is unique to the binary, put it in the binary, and pass the necessary options to your library. [ruby-debug's binary](https://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug/blob/master/bin/rdebug) is a good example. However, if your arguments are tied to your classes, such as passing around commands as in [Heroku's `Command` class](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/bin/heroku), feel free to parse the options in your library.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the answer I was looking for.